# query to get antonyms from wordnet mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordnet

I have been installed wordnet in local mysql.
I am using wordnet mysql version and I need a query to get all the antonyms of a given word.
I need to get all the antonyms of a single word.

Answer (score 0):

visit this link. It has all the queries you need
https://sourceforge.net/p/wnsqlbuilder/code2/ci/master/tree/dist/sql/mysql-wn-links-query.sql#l52